# about tofixed function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

can anyone help me how to proper use `tofixed` function in my script because im kinda new about it and when i put the tofixed my script wont work...help me please.

current script:

```
<script>
function optTotal1()
{
    var a1 = document.querySelector('select[name="optA1"]');
    var b1 = document.querySelector('select[name="optB1"]');
    var c1 = document.querySelector('select[name="optC1"]');
    var d1 = document.querySelector('select[name="optD1"]');
    var e1 = document.querySelector('select[name="optE1"]');

    if (a1.value && a1.value != "")
        a1 = parseFloat(a1.value);
    else
        a1 = 0;

    if (b1.value && b1.value != "")
        b1 = parseFloat(b1.value);
    else
        b1 = 0;

    if (c1.value && c1.value != "")
        c1 = parseFloat(c1.value);
    else
        c1 = 0;

    if (d1.value && d1.value != "")
        d1 = parseFloat(d1.value);
    else
        d1 = 0;
    if (e1.value && e1.value != "")
        e1 = parseFloat(e1.value);
    else
        e1 = 0;

      document.getElementById("total1").value.toFixed(2) = parseFloat(a1)+parseFloat(b1)+parseFloat(c1)+parseFloat(d1)+parseFloat(e1);

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap all the values with bracket then use it after you've calculated the value

```
document.getElementById("total1").value=(parseFloat(a1)+parseFloat(b1)+parseFloat(c1)+parseFloat(d1)+parseFloat(e1)).toFixed(2);
```